# Google v8 function based debugger API

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I m trying to understand how to use the v8 function based debugger API as mentioned here http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol

Could anyone please point me to any docs on how to use the API (setting breakpoints, evaluating variables etc...) as the previous link only explains the message based API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call me necromancer, but...
http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/
If you intend to implement your own debugger (for some weird reason) I guess it is a good start.
As well you can check the D8 which is provided with V8 code, check here http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/Source?tm=4